# Simple and efficient way to select non-NA data range in data frames

Tags: r, indexing, dataframe, na

Suppose you have the following data frame:

```
dat <- data.frame(a = c(1:3, NA), b = c(letters[1:3], NA), c = NA)

> dat
   a    b  c
1  1    a NA
2  2    b NA
3  3    c NA
4 NA <NA> NA
```

How do I select the non-NA region in a very efficient way?

This is what I currently use:

```
ensureNonNaRange <- function(dat) {
  idx_col <- ! sapply(dat, function(ii) all(is.na(ii)))
  idx_row <- ! sapply(1:nrow(dat), function(ii) all(is.na(unlist(dat[ii, ]))))
  dat[idx_row, idx_col]
}

> ensureNonNaRange(dat)
  a b
1 1 a
2 2 b
3 3 c
```

As only today I was pointed to the very useful function `type.convert` that I hadn't known before, I thought there might also exist something neet "of-the-shelf" like for this task in base R.

### Update

Some comparisons based on the answers/comments that I got:

```
ensureNonNaRange2 <- function(dat) {
  dat[rowSums(!is.na(dat)) != 0, colSums(!is.na(dat)) != 0]
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  a = ensureNonNaRange(dat),
  b = ensureNonNaRange2(dat)
)

Unit: microseconds
 expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval
    a 296.178 310.1070 346.2259 329.0210 349.9875 680.035   100
    b 112.313 120.0845 134.1716 125.6555 133.7200 338.112   100
```

Comment: Not off-the-shelf, but in one line: `dat[rowSums(!is.na(dat)) != 0, colSums(!is.na(dat)) != 0]`

Comment: @alistaire: neat! Almost twice as fast as mine and very compact. Thanks a lot! Wanna provide this as an answer?

Comment: What happens if e.g. `dat[2, 3]` is not NA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there may yet be some built-in function that does this, you can do it with subsetting.

When `is.na` is passed an entire `data.frame`, it makes a Boolean mask, so if you sum the rows and columns of `!is.na(dat)` (i.e. add the `TRUE` values of what is *not* `NA`), you get sums of zero for rows and columns that have *only* `NA`s.

Thus, if we subset by when our row and column sums are `!= 0`, we are left with the rows and columns with non-`NA` values:

```
> dat[rowSums(!is.na(dat)) != 0, colSums(!is.na(dat)) != 0]
  a b
1 1 a
2 2 b
3 3 c
```

If some but not all values in a row or column are NA, this approach leaves that row/column:

```
> dat[2,2] <- NA
> dat[rowSums(!is.na(dat)) != 0, colSums(!is.na(dat)) != 0]
  a    b
1 1    a
2 2 <NA>
3 3    c
```

(If you'd rather ditch rows/columns with *any* `NA`s, adjust the exclamation points, or use `complete.cases`.)

Further, it should be pretty super-fast, because `rowSums` and `colSums` are very highly optimized, so it should still work quickly on huge data structures.